# Tuleap - File size limit

Tags: file-upload, document, tuleap

In the document section there is a hint that upload size is limited to 64 MB.

We sometimes need to store huge specification documents which exceed this limit.

Is this a hard technical limitation or can this size be configured?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the file size in `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc`. Look for `$sys_max_size_upload`.

Comment: I also changed the max size for packet upload (/etc/php.ini) and for mysql (max_allowed_packet in /etc/my.cnf), but still got "You tried to upload a file that is larger than the Codendi post_max_size setting".

Comment: nb : It was possible to send the file using scp (to /var/lib/tuleap/ftp/incoming/) and then to add it.

Comment: You can find more information about the file size limit in the full install doc here: http://www.slideshare.net/Codendi/codendi-installation-guide
Especially page 15, where you have the different values, including post_max_size.